# Browse button over Image like in facebook profile picture page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my employee home page,I have a section to display the Employee profile picture. I need to implement the functionality as it is in facebook profile picture, i.e even after the image has been upload i want to display the browse image file upload button above the photo and when on hover on the image I need to have file browse button. I did like like this

```
<a onClick="myFunction()">

       <img src="@Url.Content(imgpath)" alt="image" id="image" style="width:200px;height:200px" onfocus="myFunction" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
    alert('test')
             <input type="submit" value="Upload Photo" />
}
</script>
```

but its not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hookup to the `mouseover` event of the jQuery.

When hovered on the image dynamically add the file upload html to the title of the img tag.

```
$("img").mouseover(function(){
        var fileup = "<input type=\"file\" name=\"upload\" />";
        $(this).attr("title",fileup);
});
```

then call the `.tooltip` of jQuery.

```
$(document).tooltip();
```

The default functionality of the tooltip is to close when the mouse is out of it. But we need to adjust the timout for it.

Here is the fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/4Jnk3/

Hope it helps.